# Actualizar campos de tablas sql usando Fechas y Jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jobs

Tengo dos tablas las cuales quiero actualizar en base a una Fecha de Inicio y una Fecha Final.

Tabla 1

```
ID  NUMERO      ACTIVO  FCH_INICIO       FCH_FIN               NUM_SUPL
1   508309           0   12/7/19 7:00 AM    11/7/19 8:00 AM    427592
2   508309           0   12/5/19 8:00 AM    12/5/19 9:00 AM    427592
3   50809            1   12/5/19 10:00 AM   12/5/19 12:00 PM   427592
6   508309           0   12/5/19 11:00 AM   12/5/19 12:00 PM   427592
7   508309           0   12/5/19 1:00 PM    12/5/19 2:00 PM    427592
8   508309           0   12/5/19 3:00 PM    12/5/19 4:00 PM    427592
9   508309           0   12/3/19 3:00 PM    12/3/19 4:00 PM    427592
10  605271           0   12/3/19 7:00 AM    12/3/19 8:00 AM    439870
```

Tabla 2

```
ID  NUMERO  ACTIVO  AUSENTE
1   376650    1        0
2   587995    1        0
3   605271    1        0
4   439870    1        0
5   428240    1        0
6   527863    1        0
7   433839    0        1
8   427592    1        0
9   579193    1        0
10  374981    1        0
11  515024    1        0
12  508309    1        0
```

Numero 1: mis usuarios registran en tabla1 la fecha y hora y si es del siguiente dia o del mismo dia pero una hora distinta, mi idea es hacer un job que se ejecute cada hora y si la fecha y hora es igual de la tabla1 usando getdate() que el campo ACTIVO de la tabla1 pase a 1 y en la tabla2 en base al campo NUMERO que esta entre ambos se me actualize el campo ACTIVO a 0 y AUSENTE a 1 de la tabla 2.

Numero 2: Los usuarios tambien registran la fecha final, entonces quiero hacer lo contrario de arriba, otro job que se este ejecutando cada hora y vea si la fecha y hora final en que se esta ejecutando el job es iguala la del server usando getdate(), entonces de la tabla1 actualize el campo ACTIVO a 0 y en base al campo NUMERO entre ambas actualize la tabla2 el campo ACTIVO a 1 y AUSENTE a 0.

Alguna idea de como realizar los dos puntos 1 y 2??

para el punto 1 tengo esto en el job pero no funciona:

```
Update Tabla1
set ACTIVO = 1
where ACTIVO = 0
AND CONVERT(DATETIME, FCH_INICIO) = CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE())
go
update M
set M.ACTIVO = 0
from Tabla2 as M 
inner join Tabla1 as A on A.NUMERO_GE = M.NUMERO 
where A.ACTIVO = 1 AND CONVERT(DATETIME, A.FCH_INICIO) = CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE())
go
```

y para el punto 2 tengo y tampoco funciona:

```
Update Tabla1
set ACTIVO = 0
where ACTIVO = 1
AND CONVERT(DATE, FCH_FIN) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
and DATEDIFF(Second, GETDATE(),FCH_FIN) < 3
go
```

Alguna ayuda para resolver esto??

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que tu detalle es que la conversion lo realizas a nivel DATETIME y al hacer eso nunca podras cuadrarlo por que por milesimas de segundos puede ser que el GETDATE() ya no coincida, Prueba con CAST(FCH_INICIO AS DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

Comment: @EdgarVazquez pero solo estaria tomando en cuenta la fecha y no la hora, yo busco la manera de comparar todo fecha y hora, o bien alguna otra idea quizas me cerre un poco de ideas yo solo.

Comment: Pero al usar GETDATE() nunca te hara match por que el getdate va cambiando supongamos que realiza un insert y se pone la fecha siguiente 2019-12-05 13:16:29.437 Y 5s despues hago ese el getdate me dara 2019-12-05 13:16:52.160 por lo tanto ya no entraria en vez de eso podemos usar un BETWEEN

Comment: @EdgarVazquez entonces podria sacar la direrencia entre la FCH_INICIO y GETDATE() y si es menor a 5 milisegundos que actualize o lo que tenga que hacer o algo asi?

Comment: Asi es de esa forma esta donde inicia y hasta donde llega el GETDATE() y asi deberia de traer resultados

Comment: @EdgarVazquez algun ejemplo de como quedaria?